# Зачем нужен .iml в Java?

Tags: java

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, зачем нужен .iml в Java?
Второй вопрос, где он хранится, если в IntelliJ IDEA он отображается, а по факту в папке с проектом его нет?[image: Сам файл.]

Comment: Задавать надо по одному вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IML-файл-это файл настроек модуля, созданный IntelliJ IDEA, интегрированной средой разработки (IDE), используемой для разработки Java-приложений. Он хранит информацию о модуле разработки, который является Java, плагином, Android или Maven компонентом Java - приложения.

Вот [тут](https://fileinfo.com/extension/iml) можно почитать что такое .iml файл

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)